# Docker - security concerns to publish/expose doors

Tags: docker, ubuntu

So, I'm learning Docker and trying to create an CRUD application using python + mysql just for learning purposes, only internal use with localhost, nothing beyond.  I'm using Ubuntu and I'm a bit afraid to do this.   Basically, I have 3 matters of concern about what happens when I run the following command in the terminal to run a MySQL database.

```
 " docker run -d -p 3306:3306 --name mysql-container --network (some network to connect with a python/flask container"
```

My concerns all are related with the "process of openning ports".

**Questions:**

1- What is happening behind the curtains with the port 3306 after I run this command?   I've read in some places  that it reconfigure the firewall on my machine's operational system so that port 3306 will be open to the whole Internet. I mean does this really happens? It scared me. After I run it, ANYONE in the internet will be able to access my computer? It will be like running a server? WHAT. I'm afraid with this exposure. hahah

2-  My goal is to open only for localhost. I only want to study.If I do  " `docker run -d -p 127.0.0.1:3306:3306 --network (some network)` will it be enough? How does this differ from the first command?

3- If the answer of the question 1 is :  "Yes, it has openned your computer to the whole internet." What are the risk of it? How vulnerable am I? What are the implications? Anyone can acess my computer and gain full control of it easily?  BTW, checked the Ubuntu's firewall state and it seems that the default value is off.  So I'm even more worried. hahaha

```
sudo ufw status verbose
Status: inactive
```

I know these questions might sound dumb, but I don't know much about network/security, I'm trying to understand a bit more, so please shed a light on me.

Comment: `docker run -p` with no particular IP address, from a security point of view, is the same as running the server directly on the host outside a container.  If your host system is otherwise Internet-accessible then the container will be too, and `-p 127.0.0.1:...` does mitigate that.  But if your host is behind some sort of NAT or external firewall (even a home router), Docker has no way to get around that.

Comment: @DavidMaze, but Docker also opens a door on my computer's firewall? What is stopping some external access or attack? Only the router?